# Is there an open source library for calling Windows Native API

Tags: dll, class-library, windows-kernel

I have an application that needs to call that native API (Nt*/Zw* function calls in ntdll.dll). Is there an open source library that would provide me with the datatype definitions, function prototypes, maybe even a C++ wrapper for loading and unloading the dll dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source project called NativeTest from FSLogix that will do exactly what you are looking for.  You can find the information here https://nativetest.codeplex.com/releases/view/107604